# Javascript: How to get the next 3 Mondays?

Tags: javascript, date

How do you get the next three Mondays?

For example if today is Monday, then the answer would be today, next Monday, and the next.

If today is Tuesday, then the answer would be next Monday, plus the following two Mondays.

Thank you.

Comment: Please define "current Monday". What if the current day is Saturday? What if Sunday? etc.

Comment: I have application, where customers can choose from 3 dates, for example: today it is wednesday, so they can choose only next monday and next. If today is monday, they can choose also current monday and next and next. Current monday is monday of actual week.

Comment: 5 steps: 1) `var now = new Date();` 2) `var days2add = (8-now.getDay()) % 7` this is the number of days until the next or "current" Monday. 3) `var d0 = new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate()+days2add)` 4) `var d1 = new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate()+days2add+7)` 5) `var d2 = new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate()+days2add+14)`. Then `d0`, `d1`, `d2` are your 3 Mondays.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This is exactly what i was searching for!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

d1 is the current or previous monday and d2 will be the next monday:

```
var d1 = new Date();
d1 = new Date(d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + 1 - d1.getDay())); // +1 for Monday
var d2 = new Date();
d2 = new Date(d2.setDate(d2.getDate() + 7 + 1 - d2.getDay()));
```

Comment: d gives me current monday, i can use it, thanks, but d2 gives me the same date as d

Comment: I changed the answer. Can you check this one.

Comment: This gives me current monday (3.3.2014) and next monday (10.3.2014). This is what i needed, thanks, but is there any way to get only those mondays, which will be actual? For example, today is wednesday, so customer can not make order to current monday (3.3.2014), only next monday (10.3.2014), so i cannot offer him current monday. I dont know if you understand what i need

Comment: By the way d1.getDay() gives 0 when it is sunday, this means when you check in sunday d1 will give you the next monday and d2 will give another next monday.